# My cat often leaves the litter box with urine and litter on his rear

Tags: cats, toilet-training, grooming, urination, hygiene

I have [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MRV5YNO) top-entry litter box for my cat shown below. I'm not sure if it's this box that's the problem, but he will often leave the litter box with urine on his rear which often also has litter stuck to it. This is pretty gross as it leaves little deposits wherever he sits around the house. I imagine he's squatting right on top of the litter when he pees for this to be happening. Is there anything I can do to prevent it?

[image]

Comment: Is your cat a long-hair or short-hair? With long-hair cats, they can often benefit from a "sanitary trim" to prevent this issue.

Comment: @AllisonC he's a short hair

Answer (score 4):

Try watching what he does when he uses the litterbox. It will probably be very informative.

But without being able to watch, I lean towards either the problem happens when he is about to jump out of the box, as a lot of cats sort of sit when they are preparing to jump, or that he ends up doing it because the box is too small. If it's either of those, replacing the litterbox with something that will address his problem is the obvious answer.  You might even try just a regular lidless box, because it will give the cat more room to maneuver. You can also use things other than litterboxes as litterboxes, if your cat really seems to want something bigger than the typical litterbox. For instance, a big Tupperware container can work as a litterbox.

If it's a problem of he's just squatting wrong while going, I would take him to the vet. It could just be a bizarre habit unique to him, but I don't think it's very typical behavior. Male cats I've had experience with tend to pee on the side of the box, if anything. Therefore I would make sure he doesn't have some medical issue that makes it difficult for him to squat normally.  If medical issues are ruled out though, it may just be a very unfortunate habit he has that I don't see much way of fixing. You might try taking him to a groomer to shave his rear, though. It'll at least help some at keeping himself clean, especially if he has long fur.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't consider that he might be squatting into it at the end to jump. That sounds plausible. I've taken him in before for potential urinary issues, but the vets I've seen haven't thought it was an issue. Tempted to go back to a regular box, but he really likes shoveling litter out, so I'm not sure that's much better

Comment: @mowwwalker Try a high-wall box. I use a corner high-wall box with my litter-kickers, that keeps most of the litter contained very nicely.

Comment: @AllisonC unfortunately he would shovel his litter right out of the entrance when I had a different box. Maybe if there was a litter box with an entrance at a right angle, at least he would be kicking the litter at a wall if he kicked it out of the entrance and it'd be easier to clean up.

Comment: I kind of prefer keeping it simple with litterboxes, to keep the cat as happy as possible. It seems kinder than forcing them to use some arrangement they'd prefer not to for our convenience, and reduces the odds the cat will get mad and decide somewhere in your house is better. But, you could try an arrangement where the cat still has to jump in and out, but it's not jumping directly into the litterbox. Like, there's a landing area, so if it sits while jumping, it will not be sitting in litter.

Comment: Try removing the lid. I have the same box, and my cats hated it because it’s too small. As soon as I removed the lid, it became their favorite. High-sided storage tubs (again, no lid) work too, are much cheaper and come with convenient handles.

Comment: A high-wall box designed for litter kicking cats typically also has a higher entrance; look for one like this, or as StephenS suggested, try a high-sided storage tub with no "entrance." As long as the cat isn't too old to jump in (which would be an issue with the top entry box no matter what), he shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: @mowwwalker Some cats like to dig furiously to prepare for their business, and in my experience simply having a much larger box prevents most if not all of the litter flying out in the process. As they are a lot better to maneuver in, it is also less likely they step into their feces by accident in case of diarrhea. Most litter boxes are actually way too small to use comfortably for normal sized cats, we use 85x50x18cm flat storage plastic containers you normally put under your bed for the sheets, and the cats love them.

Comment: @StephenS I think removing the lid solved the issue!! It's only been a week since I took the lid off and I haven't seen him with litter on his butt since. It could have just been a lucky week so I'll have to see if it happens again to know for sure if this worked, but so far so good, so thanks for the suggestion :)